# Running pg_dump from ShellExecuteEx()

Tags: c++, postgresql, pg-dump, shellexecuteex

When I attempt to execute pg_dump.exe with ShellExecuteEx(), it returns an exit code of 1 (failed), and I think I may be blind to a simple error I have made.

Here is the command line that works at a command prompt:

```
"C:\Program Files\PostgreSQL\9.6\bin\pg_dump.exe" --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=journaluser Journal > "C:\Google Drive\Journal\Journal20170907203244973.backup"
```

The backup file gets created with correct contents.

And here are the contents of the SHELLEXECUTEINFO structure:

```
SHELLEXECUTEINFO see = { 0 };
see.cbSize = sizeof(SHELLEXECUTEINFO);
see.fMask = SEE_MASK_NOCLOSEPROCESS;
see.hwnd = NULL;
see.lpVerb = L"open";
see.lpFile = L"C:\\Program Files\\PostgreSQL\\9.6\\bin\\pg_dump.exe";
see.lpParameters = L" --host=localhost --port=5432 --username=journaluser Journal > \"\"\"C:\\Google Drive\\Journal\\Journal20170907203244973.backup\"\"\"";
see.lpDirectory = NULL;
see.nShow = SW_SHOWNORMAL;
see.hInstApp = NULL;
```

The extra quotes in the lpParameters are because of Microsoft says at https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/bb759784(v=vs.85).aspx : "To include double quotation marks in lpParameters, enclose each mark in a pair of quotation marks, as in the following example..."

The ShellExecuteEx() calls succeeds, but the exit code is 1, and the .backup file does not get created.

I have tried various forms of the call with and without quotes, and I have tried CreateProcess(), but the results are the same -- exit code 1 and no backup file.

I have also tried using Cmd.exe as the program, with " /K (etc)" as the parameters, but that did not work.

Have I missed something simple?

Thanks.

9/8 Edit: And I forgot to mention that SetEnvironmentVariable() is used to set PGPASSWORD before the call to ShellExecuteEx(). During testing, I used GetEnvironmentVariable() to make sure the value was there.

Edit 2: I'll try Artemy's suggestion. In the meantime, I created a password file according to https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/static/libpq-pgpass.html, but it made no difference. (And for clarity, I added the missing "L" on lpParameters.)

Edit 3: As Artemy suggested, I wrote a program to be called in place of pg_dump. It just writes the command line parameters that pg_dump would ordinarily receive to a file and exits. Here are the results (no surprises; the backup file name is different because it is dynamically created from the date and time):

```
0: C:\dev\Applications\ParamTest\x64\Release\ParamTest.exe
1: --host=localhost
2: --port=5432
3: --username=journaluser
4: Journal
5: >
6: C:\Google Drive\Journal\Journal20170908093402258.backup
7: Environment password is 'qr71psgk'
```

Perhaps that result 0 line (the program name) is what's causing pg_dump to fail, if that is being passed to pg_dump. I'll track that down.

Edit 4: I worked around the problem by creating a batch file that accepts the parameters and calls pg_dump. That works, but I'd still like to know what went wrong with the other approach.

Comment: why are you using wide string for lpVerb and lpFile and narrow string for lpParameters? All 3 have same type LPCTSTR. So if you are compiling as UNICODE pass wide string to all. If you compiling without UNICODE - pass narrow string to all

Comment: @Artemy: thanks, but that's a typo from when I copied the code to Stackoverflow. In the real code, all are wide strings.

Comment: how about writing small exe that will print all received argv parameters (for example to the file line by line) and run it instead of original file to see that pg_dump.exe is really started with correct parameters? If pg_dump is still in the memory - you can see the real parameters using Task Manager without this test program